# What is the best method to use an exFAT USB between Windows and Linux without causing errors on the disk?

Tags: usb, ssd, ubuntu

I have a 2TB USB for transferring files between two systems. Everything worked fine, until I gave it accidentally a transfer in Ubutuntu 22, too big to swallow. Windows cannot repair the disk. I see differences on the disk:
Windows: can see the files and has hidden files: FOUND.000 and 'System volume Information'. However, in Ubuntu: FOUND.000 is visible, but not accessible; 'System Volume Information is visible and accessible.

On Ubuntu, I have two file managers. One can access the disk, and the other can't (Thunar File Manager). Also, the program exFatprogs can't access the disk either. I believe this is because of the FOUND.000 map.

I would like to delete the FOUND.000 directory, while not corrupting the disk any further. This directory throws an Input/output error. It was not on the disk when it was new.

Comment: Assuming you have all the data somewhere else, have you tried quick formatting it?

Comment: "Input/output error" - in general is hardware related.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Morton has said, if the data on your drive is unimportant or backed-up, then try quick formatting the drive. If that doesn't work, try regular formatting, and if that doesn't work, then boot into Ubuntu, open the terminal, unmount the drive if it has been mounted, then use `sudo su` or just `su` to log in as root, then run the following command to format it to exFAT:

`mkfs.exfat /dev/node`

Replace "node" with your USB drive's node, e.g. sda or scsi1.

If you want to keep the data on your drive, try to backup all the data on it to an online cloud drive, e.g. Google Drive, then format it, and copy all the files and directories except "FOUND.000".